# Extending Fedora lvm2 partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora

Recetly I've run out of space on my disk and I've decided to reallocate some unused space from one of the NTFS partitions to extend Fedora's partition. I've been reading about resizing LVM2 partition for quite a while now and it's super confusing for me so here's the problem with which I've been struggling for hours now:

After few manipulations, here's what I see on blivet-gui:[image]

What I would like to do now is to move "free space" into "fedora-root" in order to extend space available for use on Fedora. How can that be done?

Comment: How much of the free space do you want to assign to *fedora-root*?

Comment: Everything available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and ugly answer would be

Move the free space into a new LVM partition (just create /dev/sda7 as type LVM) - I'd probably just use fdisk, but that's just because I'm unfamiliar with blivet-gui

Add the physical disk to control under lvm

```
pvcreate /dev/sda7
```

Add the new space to the group

```
vgextend fedora /dev/sda7
```

Extend the LVM to include new space

```
lvmextend -l+100%FREE /dev/fedora/fedora-root
```

Extend the ext4 partition

```
resize2fs /dev/fedora/fedora-root
```

Not 100% sure "/dev/fedora/fedora-root" is the right device path - just use the path of your root partition